# batch script - rename copied file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Below batch script works great for copying the most recent file in a directory, but how can i rename the copied file accordingly?

```
pushd D:\sales\
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b ') do set newest=%%a
copy "%newest%" D:\test\ 
popd
```

Comment: To *really* get the newest file into variable `newest`, you need to add sort option `/o:d` to your `dir` command (unless this portion is contained in variable `DIRCMD`); to rename, append the new file name to `D:\test\` in your `copy` command line...

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "rename accordingly"? is there a fixed name, or does it need to be built programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The destination argument can be the directory to put the new file in, but you can also add the new filename to it. So instead of `D:\test\` you could do something like `D:\test\filename.ext`

Answer (score 1):

This improved code snippet renames your file to `new_name.ext`:

```
pushd D:\sales\
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /o:-d /a:-d') do (
    set "newest=%%~a"
    goto :SKIP
)
:SKIP
copy "%newest%" "D:\test\new_name.ext"
popd
```

Improvements:

- addition of new file name, of course...
- defined sort order for `dir` to get the newest file *first*, and filtered out directories to get files only; the `goto` inside of `for` breaks the loop, so there is only one iteration; this might improve performance in case of a huge number of files;
- inserted modifier `~` into `for` variable `%%a` to avoid any surrounding quotes; such are stated later at the destination in the `copy` command line;